# My localhost website using(angularjs bower components) works fine only on a particular browser and not on other computers and browser

Tags: angularjs, web, bower

This is my index.html file. I have used angularjs , bower components etc. I have used angular ui view to store header, content, footer files as templates in another folder. When I try to open "index.html" is mozilla(using it for a long time) the website opens perfectly(with all the css and scripts loaded perfectly) , but in some other browser it just shows a blank screen. I have checked in Networks developers option , there is no error in mozilla but lots of 304 and 404 errors in other browsers.Are there some issues on loading the styles and scripts on other browsers or some cached data issues?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="medicalApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>temp_App</title> 
    <!-- links to various stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/ng-dialog/css/ngDialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/ng-dialog/css/ngDialog-theme-plain.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/ng-dialog/css/ngDialog-theme-default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- I have used angular ui-view and store header, content, footer files as templates-->
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am very sorry for not adding the code earlier. Please check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to say since we can't directly interrogate your pages/scripts.  Typically a white screen in an Angularjs application is indicative of a script error (unable to load a dependency or template usually).  The Console should give you the answer.  Firefox is pretty forgiving, which is why I prefer to use Chrome.  In the failing browser look for angular errors for dependency loading.

It might be the order you are loading scripts.  Other than that I can't see anything on the surface that would a problem.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem.
The website is loading perfectly on Firefox(tried on several PC's) but doesn't loads on chrome.  Is this error due to including some angular directives like ngInclude which has some browser issues?
If so what are the other options I can use and how to resolve this error.

Comment: I often find a white screen to be an Angular dependency failure.  It may be a directive that can't load.  Things to also consider are script blockers that one browser may have installed, etc.  Check the load order of dependencies, JQuery, third party.   Chrome has some dev tools like Batarang that can help.  In the console tab of the Chrome dev tools, make sure you are set to "Verbose".  

One thing I do notice now is you should have "<base href="/">" in the head of your document.  Missing that might actually be your issue.

Comment: I should emphasize that you are missing  "<base href="/"> in the header which is likely the issue